# How bind an object from $q.all promise to $scope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

In my application, I have a service creating a new structure with two json files. So, I use $q.all to use them in a same time.

```
    angular.module('myApp', []).factory('myService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

var myStructure = function () {
    var firstJson = $http.get('datas/firstJson.json');
    var secondJson = $http.get('datas/secondJson.json');

    return $q.all([firstJson, secondJson]).then(function (values) {
        var myMap = new Map();
        /*
        treatment on myMap
        */

        return myMap.values();
    });
}

return myStructure();
}]);
```

So, I use this service in myController by using myService.then

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
myApp.controller('myApp', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
myService.myStructure.then(function(value){
    $scope.myStructure = value;
    });}]);
```

Finally, when I use {{myStructure}} in my HTML page, after instantiate myApp with ng-controller, the page display {} (an empty object).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values: Map.values() doesn't return an array as you seem to be expecting. It returns an iterator.

Comment: The problem was in Map, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Move the myMap logic inside resolve callback in the controller

Service:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory('myService', ['$http', '$q',    function ($http, $q) {

        var myStructure = function () {
            var firstJson = $http.get('datas/firstJson.json');
            var secondJson = $http.get('datas/secondJson.json');

            return $q.all([firstJson, secondJson]);
        }

        return myStructure();
    }]);
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
    myApp.controller('myApp', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
        myService.myStructure.then(function(values){
          var myMap = new Map();
          /*
          treatment on myMap
          */               
          $scope.myStructure = myMap.values();
        });
      }]);
```